# ASP.NET MVC passing data to a controller

Tags: asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing a problem for passing data to a controller.

I have a class that contains a list. I pass an instance of my object in my controller to retrieve my view. Which is actually a form. And when I submit my form, the object becomes empty, then there's that he depart at least two entries in the list. I have used the same method name to retrieve my data via Form.Method.

This is my code :

**Model**

```
public class XMLRecord
{ 
    public string TypeDoc { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Contenu { get; set; }
    public string DocName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<XMLRecord> Records { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@model  ManageXML.Models.XMLRecord

<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("HandleForm", "XMLRecord", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @role = "form", @id = "FormCreateXML" }))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <legend> XML Editor</legend>
                @if (Model.Records == null)
                { 
                    <p>None</p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <ul id="XmlEditor" style="list-style-type: none">
                        @foreach (var record in Model.Records)
                        {
                            Html.RenderPartial("XmlEditor", record);
                        }
                    </ul>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addAnother">Add another</button>
                }
        </fieldset>
        <p>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="/">Cancel</a></button>
        </p>
    }
</body>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model ManageXML.Models.XMLRecord

<li  style="padding-bottom:15px" >
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("XmlRecords")) {

        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/draggable.jpg")" height="20"width="20" style="cursor: move" alt=""/>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contenu)
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contenu)

        <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</a>
    }
</li>
```

**Controller**

```
public class XMLRecordController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult HandleForm()
    {
        var file = new XMLRecord()
        {
            Records = new List<XMLRecord>(){
                new XMLRecord(){Type="Title", Contenu="Head of Service"},
                new XMLRecord(){Type="Item", Contenu="Dr. A.Libois"}
            }
        };
        return View(file);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult HandleForm(XMLRecord file)
    {
        if (file == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("It's OK");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: only items in a for helper (except display) will be tied to the model and passed back to the controller on post

Comment: Instead of `Html.RenderPartial("XmlEditor", record);` you probably want to use an EditorTemplate. (`@Html.EditorFor(x => record)`)

Comment: Thank you for your help. dont understand Matt's comment. Can you just explain please ?

Comment: What does the `XmlEditor` partial look like?

Answer (score 0):

In your *partial view* I changed the collection's name to `Records` instead of `XMLRecords` because the name of the collection in your model is `Records`.

```
<li  style="padding-bottom:15px" >
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Records")) {

    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/draggable.jpg")" height="20"width="20" style="cursor: move" alt=""/>

        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)



        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Contenu)
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Contenu)

    <a href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().remove();">Delete</a>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your Model(`XMLRecord`) contains a member named `Record`, you have to use

`@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Records"))`

instead of

`@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("XmlRecords"))`

If the problem still exists, take a look at similar problem mentioned in [nested-begincollectionitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575732/nested-begincollectionitem/18344967#18344967).

Comment: thank you, it works ! I just changed as you mentionned and it works...Thank you for your help